# Ruby On Rails: Figure out two or more records fields value overlap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table with two fields, `range_from` and `range_to`. Both fields are integer.
If one record's `range_from` is less than last record's `range_to`, then get `false`, otherwise, get `true`.

For example:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | range_from | range_to |
+----+------------+----------+
| 1  | 4          | 10       |
| 2  | 6          | 12       |
+----+------------+----------+
```

Because 6 < 10, so I should get `false`.

I found a gem named "validate-overlaps", but it looks like to deal with `DateTime` overlap.

It's ok validate this from model or controller.

Comment: does making a method in model to do this simple validation doesnot work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shivam suggested, you can write a method. Something like:

```
def validate_range
  self.errors.add(:range_from, "is less than the last range_to") unless (self.range_from > Model.last.range_to)
end
```